# SSLSocketFactory.createSocket connects using http instead of https

Tags: http, https, handshake

I need to make a handshake. I do it with the code below.

I'm running the code in an applet and it works fine when running directly against the server. The problem I have occurs when the same code runs via a proxy. 
I'm looking in the java console with trace level 5 activated. Directly after the code line "SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("www.theserver.com", 443);" is executed 
this line appears in the java console "network: Connecting http://www.theserver.com:443 with proxy=DIRECT". After this the applet stops working. I think it is because the 
proxy will not allow http traffic on port 443.

Can anyone tell me why it is connecting using http and what I should do to make it connect using https?

```
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent; 
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener; 
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket; 
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory; 

public class Handshake 
{ 

    class MyHandshakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener 
    { 

        public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Handshake succesful!"); 
            System.out.println("Using cipher suite: " + e.getCipherSuite()); 
        } 
    } 

    public void DoHandshake() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(); 
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("www.theserver.com", 443); 
            String[] suites = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites(); 
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites); 
            socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyHandshakeListener()); 
            socket.startHandshake(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            System.out.println(e); 
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: I think I'm looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but we had the exact same problem and was just able to resolve it.  The problem was on the client, the "Use SSL 2.0 compatible ClientHello format" was checked on the advanced tab of the Java Control Panel.  Uncheck this box on the client and it will connect correctly.